# Placing 2 Divs on the Same Line when Using "Order" in Flexbox Without Adjusting the HTML Markup (CSS) when you CAN'T modify the Markup

Tags: css, divi

I'm using a plugin called Divi Blog Extras which is using "Order" in CSS to position DIV containers. I am attempting to put two divs (.post-meta and .post-categories) next to each other now that I've corrected the order so it matches my customer's designs, but I am struggling to get them next to each other.

I have tried floats, inline styles, and flexing, but nothing seems to affect how they position themselves. It looks like something that should be relatively straightforward yet I cannot get these to line up as they should.

Do you have any suggestions I could use (*without absolutely positioning these - unless that's the only way*)?

This is the DEMO website where to code can be seen (blog article item):
https://miles.birdhouse-demos.com/blog/

This is what this blog item looks like out of the box:
https://snipboard.io/hL5dqe.jpg

This is the goal based don't the client's designs:
https://snipboard.io/IZEtmY.jpg

**Thank you in advance!**

[image: HTML MARKUP]

Answer (score 0):

You can move both of those items into a new  and then style that div to position them side by side

```
<div style="
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
">
  <p class="post-meta">...</p>
  <div class="post-categories">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get this result.
 [image]

By doing the following:
Put the `p` tag inside the `div`.
From this:

```
<p class="post-meta"> <span class="read-time"><span class="et-pb-icon"></span>2 min read</span></p>

<div class="post-categories"><a href="https://miles.birdhouse-demos.com/category/mental-health/" target="_self" rel="category term tag" class="el_category_term el_term_mental-health">Mental Health</a></div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="post-categories"><a href="https://miles.birdhouse-demos.com/category/mental-health/" target="_self" rel="category term tag" class="el_category_term el_term_mental-health">Mental Healthggg</a>|<p class="post-meta"><span class="read-time"><span class="et-pb-icon"></span>2 min read</span></p></div>
```

And changing some styles, from this:

```
categories {
    width: 48%!important;
    padding: 0!important;


.et_pb_post_extra.el_dbe_block_extended .post-meta {
    border-top: none;
    padding: 10px 0 0 5px!important;

}
```

To this:

```
categories {
    width: 100%!important;
    padding: 0!important;


.et_pb_post_extra.el_dbe_block_extended .post-meta {
    border-top: none;
    padding: 10px 0 0 5px!important;
    display:inline;

}
```